# My pi keeps disassociating with my wifi

Tags: wifi

My Raspberry pi 3 keeps disassociating with my WiFi at random and i don't know why. I have tried rebooting the pi and updating it but the issue keeps occurring.

Comment: What power supply do you have? I spent 3 weeks tracking WiFi issues till I used a real pi power supply and then went as soon as I swapped the supply.

Comment: i just use the standard plug which came with the pi.

Comment: Sorry but that does not help - is it one from Raspberry Pi Trading or just a generic?  It will help others (and stop having the question closed) to give details of your network set up and any other devices.  As of now there is so little to go on it's anyone guess.

Comment: Add `iwconfig wlan0 power off` to /etc/rc.local to disable the WiFi going to low power when it's idle.

Comment: What operating system, what version do you use?